# Samba shares - How to restrict access to Active Directory groups

Tags: samba, active-directory, smb, nss

I'm working in an Active Directory domain environment and am trying to configure some Samba shares so certain directories on a SUSE UNIX server are accessible by Windows clients.

Access to each share needs to be restricted to a particular AD group.

My smb.conf file looks as follows, but when navigating to the share form Windows I receive a credentials prompt or access denied message. I'm also seeing slightly different messages in the Samba logs when I browse to the the server using \\SERVER_NAME or \\IP_ADDRESS.

```
[global]
    netbios name = SERVER-NAME
    security = domain
    realm = MYDOMAIN.ORG.UK
    workgroup = MYDOMAIN
    password server = *
    idmap config * : range = 10000-20000

    cups options = raw
    kerberos method = secrets and keytab
    logon path = \\%L\profiles\.msprofile
    logon home = \\%L\%U\.9xprofile
    logon drive = P:
    map to guest = Bad User
    passdb backend = tdbsam
    null passwords = yes
    printing = cups
    printcap name = cups
    printcap cache time = 750
    template homedir = /home/%D/%U
    template shell = /bin/bash
    usershare allow guests = no

    winbind refresh tickets = yes
    winbind offline logon = yes
    winbind cache time = 10
    winbind enum users = yes
    winbind enum groups = yes
    winbind use default domain = yes

    log file = /var/log/samba/samba.log
    max log size = 1000
    log level = 2

[share1]
        path = /path/to/share/1
        read only = yes
        browseable = yes
        valid users = @ad-group-for-share-1

[share2]
        path = /path/to/share/2
        read only = no
        browseable = yes
        valid users = @ad-group-for-share-2
```

The samba log shows the following when browsing to \\servername\share1...

```
[2019/05/30 11:21:01.182411,  1] ../source3/auth/token_util.c:431(add_local_groups)
  SID S-1-5-21-2037406089-871956902-1971066577-68326 -> getpwuid(10010) failed
[2019/05/30 11:21:01.182460,  1] ../source3/auth/auth_generic.c:172(auth3_generate_session_info_pac)
  Failed to map kerberos pac to server info (NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL)
[2019/05/30 11:21:01.203035,  3] ../source3/lib/util_procid.c:54(pid_to_procid)
  pid_to_procid: messaging_dgm_get_unique failed: No such file or directory
```

The Samba log shows the following when browsing to \\ip-address\share1

```
[2019/05/30 11:22:01.416559,  2] ../source3/auth/auth.c:305(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  authentication for user [MY-USERNAMER] -> [MY-USERNAME] -> [my-username] succeeded
[2019/05/30 11:22:01.417038,  1] ../source3/auth/token_util.c:431(add_local_groups)
  SID S-1-5-21-2037406089-871956902-1971066577-68326 -> getpwuid(10010) failed
[2019/05/30 11:22:01.417425,  1] ../source3/auth/token_util.c:431(add_local_groups)
  SID S-1-5-21-2037406089-871956902-1971066577-68326 -> getpwuid(10010) failed
[2019/05/30 11:22:01.436657,  3] ../source3/lib/util_procid.c:54(pid_to_procid)
  pid_to_procid: messaging_dgm_get_unique failed: No such file or directory
```

What am I missing?
How can I troubleshoot this?
What needs to be done to have these shares accessible by Windows clients?

Comment: Forgot to add I'm running Samba version 4.6.16-git.154.2998451b9123.40.3-SUSE-SLE_12-x86_64